# Does Sentry automatic "Performance Queries" in Asp.Net work?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sentry

I'm trying to capture the SQL Server queries in my web app's backend with Sentry. It's a very large and old application so switching to Core or manually adding Spans isn't an option but based on the documentation it sounds like it should automatically capture them by adding a few options in the Sentry Init. I've followed the documentation closely and experimented with several other options that supposedly aren't needed like AddDiagnosticSourceIntegration() all with no luck.

Is this a Sentry feature that isn't supported in older Asp.Net 4.8 apps? If it is supported, does anyone know where a good working example might exist?

Comment: As this is more about capturing SQL Server queries than web requests, does the application you're instrumenting use Entity Framework or does it use something else to communicate with SQL Server?

Comment: Even raw SQL client queries should be captured with: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnet/performance/instrumentation/automatic-instrumentation/ though. Otherwise we might have a bug?

Comment: Can't you capture queries using XEvents instead?

Comment: There is a little EF in the mix but it's mostly SqlClient (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlParameter). 

As far as XEvents, yes, we can and do use a variety of different tools to capture query performance data. However, we've just added Sentry to collect the web page performance and issues information, and, if it can also collect and corollate the query data into it's collected info that would be very helpful. So far Sentry has been a great addition and we'd like to take advantage of what it has to offer.

Comment: That's great to hear @Jay13, if this isn't working we might need to adjust something. Please feel free to open a ticket here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/new/choose if the documentation I linked above doesn't work for you. It should capture SqlClient as well as EF, and EF Core queries. We're also on Discord if you want to chat discord.gg/sentry on channel #dotnet

Comment: Thank you Bruno, I'll get a ticket started.